# Contraction mapping theorem in $\mathbb R^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is:

Show that there exists a unique $(x_1,y_1)\in \mathbb R^{2}$ such that $\cos(\sin(x_1)) = y_1$ and $\sin(\cos(y_1)) = x_1.$

My attempt to a solution:

Let $F(x)= \begin{bmatrix}\sin(\cos(y_1)) \\ \cos(\sin(x_1)) \end{bmatrix}$, where $x=(x_1,y_1)\in \mathbb R^2$. I then tried proving that F is a contraction to use the contraction mapping theorem. I tried doing this by:

1) Calculating the Jacobean of $F$: $$F’(x)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 && -\cos(\cos(y_1))\sin(y_1) \\ -\sin(\sin(x_1))\cos(x_1) && 0 \end{bmatrix},$$ and using the matrix metric $\Vert.\Vert_{\infty}$ to prove $\Vert F’(x)\Vert_{\infty}\le c$, where $c<1$, and thus $F$ is a contraction by contraction property. But that didn’t work since I can’t bound $\vert \cos(\cos(y_1))\sin(y_1)\vert$ or $\vert\sin(\sin(x_1))\cos(x_1)\vert$ by anything smaller than $1$.

2) Proving F is a contraction straight from definition:

I tried doing this using the metric $d(x,y)=\max\{|x_1-y_1|, |x_2-y_2|\}$, where $x=(x_1,x_2)$ and $y=(y_1,y_2)$, but I ran into the same problem as above. I also tried Euclidean metric but had no luck.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem or spot any mistake in my reasoning above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by the OP, $|\sin(t)|\le1<\pi/2$ implies that there exists $\lambda<1$ such that $|\sin(\sin(t))|\le\lambda$, hence $$|\sin(\sin(t))\cos(t)|\le\lambda.$$

Alas the most that can be said about the other entry in the Jacobian is that its modulus does not exceed $1$.

It turns out that this does imply that $F$ is a strict contraction in a certain weighted $\ell_1$ norm.

Writing $x=(x_1,x_2)$ as usual instead of the somewhat idiosyncratic notation in  the OP, for $\alpha>0$ define a norm on $\Bbb R^2$ by $$||x||_\alpha=|x_1|+\alpha|x_2|.$$If $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix let $||A||_\alpha$ be the corresponding operator norm $$||A||_\alpha=\sup_{||x||_\alpha=1}||Ax||_\alpha.$$

> > **Straightforward Calculation** $\left|\left|\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right|\right|_\alpha
> > \le\max(|a|+\alpha|c|,|b|/\alpha+|d|)$.

Hence $$||F'(x)||_\alpha\le\max(\lambda\alpha,1/\alpha).$$ So if $1<\alpha<1/\lambda$ it follows that $||F'(x)||_\alpha\le\beta<1$, hence $F$ is a strict contraction in the metric $d(x,y)=||x-y||_\alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively it is possible to boil down the problem to $\mathbb{R}^1$ by realizing that if there exists $(x_1,y_1)\in \mathbb R^{2}$ such that $\cos(\sin(x_1)) = y_1$ and $\sin(\cos(y_1)) = x_1$, then necessarily $x_1$ is the unique fixed point of $f(x) = \sin(\cos(\cos(\sin(x))))$.

But does the converse statement holds? That is, are these statements equivalent?

Computing $f'$ and analyzing its absolute value one can conclude that
$$ |f'(x)| = |\cos (\cos (\cos (\sin (x)))) \cdot \sin (\cos (\sin (x))) \cdot \sin (\sin (x)) \cdot \cos (x)| < 1$$

Therefore $f$ has an unique fixed point, say $x_1$. Now, by the definition of function, there exists an unique $y_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos(\sin(x_1)) = y_1$. Hence the result.